# ReactJS with Google Maps - displaying one info window at any time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I am using react-google-maps and I am able to display the marker and InfoWindow - which is working correctly, but I only want to show the current active marker window.

I'm using the isOpen state to store the current marker and showing if it matches the current key but it still lets you click and toggle all the markers info windows. I suspect I'm making a very simple mistake but I'm pretty new to ReactJS. Also, please note that I've found very similar questions but none have helped me solve this issue.

Here's my code..

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isOpen: '',
    }

}

handleToggleOpen = (e) => {

   this.setState({
       isOpen: e
   });

   console.log(e);
   console.log('current state is... ');
   console.log(this.state.isOpen);
}

handleToggleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: null
    });
}

render() {

    // console.log(this.props.marker.id)

    return (

            <div>
        <Marker
            key={this.props.marker.id}
            position={{ lat: parseFloat(this.props.marker.acf.locations.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.marker.acf.locations.lng)}}
              icon={{
               url: this.props.icon,
               optimized: false,
               scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 37),
             }}
             onClick={() =>  this.handleToggleOpen(this.props.marker.id)}
             audioPlay={this.props.audioPlay} >

                {
                        this.state.isOpen === this.props.marker.id && (
                     <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.handleToggleClose}>
                        <div>
                         <h3 className="infowindow__title">{this.props.marker.title.rendered} {this.props.marker.acf.title_sub} </h3>
                         <span onClick={() =>this.refs.componentToDisplay.showPopup()} className="infowindow__link underline">Learn more</span>
                        </div>
                     </InfoWindow>)
                    }

            <PlacePopup ref="componentToDisplay" title={this.props.marker.title.rendered} intro={this.props.marker.acf.text} id={this.props.marker.id} subtitle={this.props.marker.acf.title_sub} audio={this.props.marker.acf.file} audioPlay={this.props.audioPlay}  >
                        </PlacePopup>
        </Marker> 
    </div>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each of your markers has its own state, you'll have to find a way to be able to connect every state object of each marker component. The reason why you would need the state of each marker is that when one of the markers is being clicked, it must notify all the other markers that there is a marker being clicked, so if they have their windows open they must close it immediately. In this case, I would suggest solving this problem using Redux (since you said that you're still new to React, I'm not quite sure if you're already familiar with Redux or not, so if you do please tell me in the comments and I will try to help provide a solution using Redux). I believe that you may still manage to solve the problem without the help of Redux, however it might become really complex and hard to control in the future.

Furthermore, there are a couple things in your code that I think need to be fixed first. It would be much better for `isOpen` inside your state to be set as a boolean instead of a string. So here are the changes your should make to your code:

1. In your constructor, initialize `isOpen`:

   this.state = {
       isOpen: false
   }
2. Inside your handleToggleOpen function, there is no need to pass any parameter, so you may remove the `e`:

   handleToggleOpen = () => {
       this.setState({
           isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
       });
   }

This is basically what toggle is, so you may delete your `handleToggleClose` function as well (as `handleToggleOpen` handles both open and close), then replace it with `handleToggleOpen` inside your render function.

3. Now you only have to change

`this.state.isOpen === this.props.marker.id &&`

into simply

```
this.state.isOpen &&
```

then it should work as it is supposed to be, without having the need to compare the id of each marker every time.

Comment: Thank you for explaining so brilliantly. I really appreciate the explanation of why the current code won't work and the improvements to my code. 
I already have Redux set up, so I'm going to implement that myself, mainly because I think I'll learn more by practicing. Thank you